# Were do I find local Joomla installation on XAMPP?

Tags: php, apache, joomla, xampp, migration

I know that I'm missing something obvious here. I installed XAMPP on my Mac to develop a Joomla site locally. Everything has gone fine and I'm now ready to migrate to my site to my external server, but I can't find it...

The [Joomla documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_website_from_localhost_to_a_remote_host) says that the local directory using XAMPP should be at xampp/www/directory, but there is no "www" folder anywhere in Applications/XAMPP and I can't find any other xampp folders anywhere on my hard drive. Where do I find the files I need to FTP to the server??

All help very appreciated!

Comment: `sudo find / -name index.php`.

Comment: We can't really help you, since we do not have access to your local hard drive :)

Comment: Marc B, that did it, thanks so incredibly much! I used Bitnami to install Joomla and it hid it in a restricted folder where it wouldn't show up in Spotlight searches. You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find command to fine php files for your joomla installation :) Eg:

```
find / -name index.php
```